# Extending functionalitty (aka Modifying) visual studio C/C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, compiler-construction

I want to extend the features of C/C++ compiler used in Visual studio. Basically, I want to write a tool which parses the c/c++ code and prints out where all branching (if check, break statement, for/while loops, etc) happens in the code. Then I would like to use this information while executing code to grey out areas of code that have not been executed, for a given testcase.

Is it possible? Does Microsoft provide any way to add features to its compiler/debugger?

--Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all answers. Although they are all good, I can't upvote as I don't have enough reputation :(

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's compilers always were a black box. (Taken from their own site from the upcoming link). So you have a chance that it is not possible right now. But with project [Roslyn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx) that's about to be changed.

Anyway, it seems to me you shouldn't look into the compiler but the debugging part of Visual Studio. There are [APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/bb147088.aspx) that allow you to interact with the debugger and that's probably the road you want to take (and others did take).

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that debugger is better than compiler for understnding where the branching points in the source code are. I don't believe the debugger "knows" this sort of thing, so you'd have to reverse engineer the information by finding branches in the resulting binary, and then look up where in the source that belongs to. 

I would add that this is definitely not a simple/small task - even if you have source for the compiler! [Not that understanding compiler code is easy either!]

Comment: @Sascha, I took a look at Roslyn and the APIs you mentioned. While Roslyn is not useful for my needs, The APIs combined with something like what Clifford mentioned may solve my problem.

Comment: @Sascha, I looked at the APIs and they seem to be support some breakpoint related functionality, as far as this problem goes. If the debugger (somehow) gives information about branching, then I will not need to look at compiler part.

Comment: @Mats Peterrson, I agree with the difficulty. My day job is in compilers! However, looks like there are some workarounds as suggested in other answers

Answer (score 0):

You would not normally do that by modifying the compiler, and with Microsoft's compiler you cannot in any case. Rather you would write a preproccessor that *instruments* the code (inserts additional code at the conditional nodes to trace the control flow), and then a tool that process the trace data to determine what ran.

Visual Studio itself has [an add-in architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc52cke4.aspx) that would allow you to render this data in the editor in the manner you describe.

The instrumentation itself is not trivial - it will need to be able to parse all valid C and C++ code and be able to retain the original line number information so that the uninstrumented code can be presented.  For completeness it would have to be able to re-factor code using the ternary ?: operator so that its flow could be instrumented.  The instrumented code would also need to be the code output by the standard pre-processor rather than the original source code - making line number tracking a little more difficult (although the preprocesor already manages that for use with the debugger).

Comment: Thanks. I think a combination of preprocessor and APIS will help. I do understand that completeness for this problem can be tough, but my productivity will improve even if I can 50% of this!

Comment: @user763410: Note that Visual Studio Ultimate and Premium editions already include [Code Coverage Analysis](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare).  It would probably be more cost-effective to use that than to code it yourself.  There are a number OF third-party tools that may suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use preprocessor to instrument code. Code should spit out a file while running. At breakpoints, process this information and "grey out" code using debugger APIs + visual studio addin mechanism.